# Download AWS CloudWatch logs for a period

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, loops, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to download all CloudWatch logs from AWS for:

- a spectific log group
- a specific time range

My plan is fairly simple:

1. Iterate over all logstreams for log group.
2. For each log stream iterate over events and build a list of all log events.

```py
import boto3


def overlaps(start1, end1, start2, end2):
    return max(start1, start2) < min(end1, end2)


def load_logs(region, group, start=0, end=2672995600000):
    client = boto3.client('logs', region_name=region)
    paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_log_streams')

    response_iterator = paginator.paginate(logGroupName=group)
    events = []
    for page in response_iterator:
        for log_stream in page["logStreams"]:
            print(f"Stream: {log_stream['logStreamName']}, start: {log_stream['firstEventTimestamp']} end: {log_stream['lastEventTimestamp']}")
            if overlaps(log_stream["firstEventTimestamp"], log_stream["lastEventTimestamp"], start, end):
                print("processing")
                token = None
                while True:
                    event_args = {
                        "logGroupName": group,
                        "logStreamName": log_stream['logStreamName'],
                        "startTime": start,
                        "endTime": end
                    }

                    if token is not None:
                        event_args["nextToken"] = token

                    response = client.get_log_events(**event_args)

                    for event in response["events"]:
                        if start < event["timestamp"] < end:
                            events.append(event)

                    if response["nextBackwardToken"] == token:
                        break
                    else:
                        token = response["nextBackwardToken"]

    print(events)
```

I'm passing `0` as a `start` and a far future `2672995600000` as `end` and some events are downloaded, however `events` list does not contain all logevents. Is there some iteration I'm missing? I'm especially concerned with `get_log_events` [iteration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_log_events)

Answer (score 1):

Starting the query does not return log lines but a query id.
You need to get query results.

```
import boto3
REGION = 'us-east-1' # replace with your region

client = boto3.client('logs', region_name=REGION)

CONCLUDED_QUERY_EXECUTION_STATUSES = ['Complete', 'Failed', 'Cancelled', 'Timeout']  # |'Unknown'
SEPARATOR = "MY_SEPARATOR"

def query(start_time: int or float, end_time: int or float):
    """ runs a query

    :param start_time: The beginning of the time range to query. The range is inclusive, so the specified start time is included in the query. Specified as epoch time, the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.
    :param end_time: The end of the time range to query. The range is inclusive, so the specified end time is included in the query. Specified as epoch time, the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.
    :return: a list of log lines
    """
    # STEP 1: prepare and start your query, you'll get a query id
    body = dict(
        logGroupName='YOUR_LOG_GROUP_HERE',
        startTime=round(start_time),
        endTime=round(end_time),
        queryString='fields @timestamp, @message' # complete your query if needed
    )
    response = client.start_query(**body)

    # STEP 2: wait for query result
    query_id = response.get('queryId')
    response = client.get_query_results(
        queryId=query_id
    )
    while response.get('status') not in CONCLUDED_QUERY_EXECUTION_STATUSES:
        print(f"[{i:4}]\t Query status: {response.get('status')}", end='\r')
        time.sleep(5) # wait a bit before retrying
        response = client.get_query_results(
            queryId=query_id
        )
    print(f"[DONE]\tQuery status: {response.get('status')}")


    return [f"{r[0]['value']}{SEPARATOR}{r[1]['value']}" for r in response.get('results')]
```

Answer (score 1):

little late to the party I know but this worked for me...

Essentially just sorting by timestamp and moving the start time of the query every time -- be careful of timezone. Caught me up for a while.

```
import time

import boto3
from datetime import datetime

import pytz as pytz
from boto3 import Session

client = boto3.client('sts')
#ASSUME ROLE
response = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="YourARN",
    RoleSessionName='A UNIQUE SESSION'
)

new_session = Session(
    aws_access_key_id=response["Credentials"]["AccessKeyId"],
    aws_secret_access_key=response["Credentials"]["SecretAccessKey"],
    aws_session_token=response["Credentials"]["SessionToken"]
)

#YOUR QUERY(FIELDS REQUIRED)
query = 'fields  @message, @timestamp | sort @timestamp asc | limit 10000'

log_group = 'LOG GROUP NAME'

start = datetime(2023, 5, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC)
end = datetime(2023, 5, 29, 23, 59, 59, 9999, pytz.UTC)


def query_cloud_watch_paginated(start_val, end_val):
    mthd_client = new_session.client("logs")
    start_query_response = mthd_client.start_query(
        logGroupName=log_group,
        startTime=int(start_val.timestamp()),
        endTime=int(end_val.timestamp()),
        queryString=query
    )

    query_id = start_query_response["queryId"]
    response_val = None
    while response_val is None or response_val['status'] == 'Running':
        time.sleep(1)
        response_val = mthd_client.get_query_results(
            queryId=query_id
        )

    return response_val


def action_data(dictionaryOfCloudwatchResponses):
    '''do you required stuff over here.'''
    print(len(dictionaryOfCloudwatchResponses["results"]))



tmp_response = query_cloud_watch_paginated(start, end)
start_val = datetime.strptime(tmp_response["results"][-1][1]["value"]+' +0000','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z') # INCLUDE TIMEZONE!
while len(tmp_response) > 0 and start_val < end: #YOU MAY WANT TO WORK ON THIS CONDITION....
    action_data(tmp_response)
    start_val = datetime.strptime(tmp_response["results"][-1][1]["value"]+' +0000','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z') #UGLY HACK FIX IF YOU WANT :-)
    tmp_response = query_cloud_watch_paginated(start_val=start_val, end_val=end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start_query` it will return all logs from all logstreams.

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

client = boto3.client('logs')

query = "fields @timestamp, @message"

log_group = 'NAME_OF_YOUR_LOG_GROUP'

start_query_response = client.start_query(
    logGroupName=log_group,
    startTime=int((datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=24)).timestamp()),
    endTime=int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
    queryString=query,
)
```

Comment: Thanks. How to paginate query results though?

Comment: Paginator is not allowed for this methods 
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2456#issuecomment-634327782